# Show simple content of XHTML in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to learn, and I can show an XHTML file content in a DIV, unused IFRAME.

This is me test:

**index.xhtml**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Load</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#botton").click(function(event) {
                    $("#cap").load('test.xhtml');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="cap">Click!!!.</div>
    <br>
    <input name="boton" id="botton" type="button" value="Update cap." />
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Content</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="content">Show content, YES.</div>
      <div id="hidden">I don't show</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Error console Chrome:**
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///??????/test.xhtml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Thanks you all!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are not using a web server to serve your files but your file system. You url is probably `file://index.html` therefor, when you try to do a `load(file)`, it will be relative to the current domain wich is file://.

The error message is pretty obvious : `CORS can only be used with these protocol : http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource`.

Either load the file with `http://file` or use a webserver for your test.

Comment: The test is file:///pro/test.xhtml in Chrome, and works well. is it not possible to use it without http?, is sample file xhtml.